# Getting started for JSF in WebSphere Community Edition v3

Tags: html, eclipse, jsf-2, websphere-ce

I am trying to create a JSF2.0 application in WebSphere Community Edition v3 in Eclipse. I already installed plugin for WebSphere Community Edition v3 and JSFv2.0 (Apache MyFaces) with JSTLv1.2 but i don't know how to start in WebSphere. I have worked in Tomcat 7.0.11 previously but in WebSphere Community Edition v3, i am confused. Can somebody please tell me how to create a simple JSF2.0 application in WebSphere Community Edition v3 and which are the libraries which one must include while working JSF with WebSphere Community Edition v3. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I did a blunder mistake. While talking about necessary libraries everything is same in both Tomcat and WebSphere.